# Mupx deployment fails. Why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, reactjs, docker

I'm trying to deploy [Telescope](https://github.com/TelescopeJS/Telescope) to a simple Ubuntu 16.04 server. So I'm using the suggested deployment with [MupX](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up/tree/mupx). After setting up the mup.json file, I did a `mupx deploy`:

```
$ mupx setup

Meteor Up: Production Quality Meteor Deployments
------------------------------------------------
Configuration file : mup.json
Settings file      : settings.json


Started TaskList: Setup (linux)
[146.185.181.9] - Installing Docker
[146.185.181.9] - Installing Docker: SUCCESS
[146.185.181.9] - Setting up Environment
[146.185.181.9] - Setting up Environment: SUCCESS
[146.185.181.9] - Copying MongoDB configuration
[146.185.181.9] - Copying MongoDB configuration: SUCCESS
[146.185.181.9] - Installing MongoDB
[146.185.181.9] - Installing MongoDB: SUCCESS
```

No problems there, so after this I tried a `mupx deploy`, but that ends with an error:

```
$ mupx deploy

Meteor Up: Production Quality Meteor Deployments
------------------------------------------------
Configuration file : mup.json
Settings file      : settings.json

Meteor app path    : /Users/kramer65/dev/repos/Telescope
Using buildOptions : {}
nova:rss: updating npm dependencies -- rss...

Changes to your project's package version selections:

reactrouter:react-router-ssr  downgraded from 3.1.4 to 3.1.3


Started TaskList: Deploy app 'telescope' (linux)
[146.185.181.9] - Uploading bundle
[146.185.181.9] - Uploading bundle: SUCCESS
[146.185.181.9] - Sending environment variables
[146.185.181.9] - Sending environment variables: SUCCESS
[146.185.181.9] - Initializing start script
[146.185.181.9] - Initializing start script: SUCCESS
[146.185.181.9] - Invoking deployment process
[146.185.181.9] - Invoking deployment process: SUCCESS
[146.185.181.9] - Verifying deployment
[146.185.181.9] x Verifying deployment: FAILED

    -----------------------------------STDERR-----------------------------------
     run:
    npm WARN deprecated
    npm WARN deprecated   npm -g install npm@latest
    npm WARN deprecated
    npm WARN deprecated (Depending on how Node.js was installed on your system, you
    npm WARN deprecated may need to prefix the preceding commands with `sudo`, or if
    npm WARN deprecated on Windows, run them from an Administrator prompt.)
    npm WARN deprecated
    npm WARN deprecated If you're running the version of npm bundled with
    npm WARN deprecated Node.js 0.10 LTS, be aware that the next version of 0.10 LTS
    npm WARN deprecated will be bundled with a version of npm@2, which has some small
    npm WARN deprecated backwards-incompatible changes made to `npm run-script` and
    npm WARN deprecated semver behavior.
    npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No description
    npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No repository field.
    npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No README data

    > fibers@1.0.8 install /bundle/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers
    > node build.js || nodejs build.js

    -----------------------------------STDOUT-----------------------------------

    To see more logs type 'mup logs --tail=50'

    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So I checked what the logs said:

```
$ mupx logs --tail=50

Meteor Up: Production Quality Meteor Deployments
------------------------------------------------
Configuration file : mup.json
Settings file      : settings.json

[146.185.181.9]     at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime/.npm/package/node_modules/install/install.js:141:1)
[146.185.181.9]     at require (packages/modules-runtime/.npm/package/node_modules/install/install.js:75:1)
[146.185.181.9]     at packages/react-meteor-data/createContainer.jsx:10:16
[146.185.181.9] npm WARN deprecated This version of npm lacks support for important features,
[146.185.181.9] npm WARN deprecated such as scoped packages, offered by the primary npm
[146.185.181.9] npm WARN deprecated registry. Consider upgrading to at least npm@2, if not the
[146.185.181.9] npm WARN deprecated latest stable version. To upgrade to npm@2, run:
[146.185.181.9] npm WARN deprecated
[146.185.181.9] npm WARN deprecated   npm -g install npm@latest-2
[146.185.181.9] npm WARN deprecated
[146.185.181.9] npm WARN deprecated To upgrade to the latest stable version, run:
[146.185.181.9] npm WARN deprecated
[146.185.181.9] npm WARN deprecated   npm -g install npm@latest
[146.185.181.9] npm WARN deprecated
[146.185.181.9] npm WARN deprecated (Depending on how Node.js was installed on your system, you
[146.185.181.9] npm WARN deprecated may need to prefix the preceding commands with `sudo`, or if
[146.185.181.9] npm WARN deprecated on Windows, run them from an Administrator prompt.)
[146.185.181.9] npm WARN deprecated
[146.185.181.9] npm WARN deprecated If you're running the version of npm bundled with
[146.185.181.9] npm WARN deprecated Node.js 0.10 LTS, be aware that the next version of 0.10 LTS
[146.185.181.9] npm WARN deprecated will be bundled with a version of npm@2, which has some small
[146.185.181.9] npm WARN deprecated backwards-incompatible changes made to `npm run-script` and
[146.185.181.9] npm WARN deprecated semver behavior.
[146.185.181.9] npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No description
[146.185.181.9] npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No repository field.
[146.185.181.9] npm WARN package.json meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No README data
[146.185.181.9] npm WARN cannot run in wd meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 node npm-rebuild.js (wd=/bundle/bundle/programs/server)
[146.185.181.9] => Starting meteor app on port:80
[146.185.181.9] WARNING: npm peer requirements (for react-meteor-data) not installed:
[146.185.181.9]  - react@15.x not installed.
[146.185.181.9]  - react-addons-pure-render-mixin@15.x not installed.
[146.185.181.9]
[146.185.181.9] Read more about installing npm peer dependencies:
[146.185.181.9]   http://guide.meteor.com/using-packages.html#peer-npm-dependencies
[146.185.181.9]
[146.185.181.9]
[146.185.181.9] /bundle/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/future.js:267
[146.185.181.9]                         throw(ex);
[146.185.181.9]                               ^
[146.185.181.9] Error: Can't find npm module 'react'. Did you forget to call 'Npm.depends' in package.js within the 'modules-runtime' package?
[146.185.181.9]     at Object.Npm.require (/bundle/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:195:17)
[146.185.181.9]     at options.fallback (packages/modules-runtime/modules-runtime.js:21:1)
[146.185.181.9]     at require (packages/modules-runtime/.npm/package/node_modules/install/install.js:81:1)
[146.185.181.9]     at meteorInstall.node_modules.meteor.react-meteor-data.createContainer.jsx (packages/react-meteor-data/createContainer.jsx:5:1)
[146.185.181.9]     at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime/.npm/package/node_modules/install/install.js:141:1)
[146.185.181.9]     at require (packages/modules-runtime/.npm/package/node_modules/install/install.js:75:1)
[146.185.181.9]     at meteorInstall.node_modules.meteor.react-meteor-data.react-meteor-data.jsx (packages/react-meteor-data/react-meteor-data.jsx:7:25)
[146.185.181.9]     at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime/.npm/package/node_modules/install/install.js:141:1)
[146.185.181.9]     at require (packages/modules-runtime/.npm/package/node_modules/install/install.js:75:1)
[146.185.181.9]     at packages/react-meteor-data/createContainer.jsx:10:16
```

In these logs I read something about React not being installed. But as far as I can see, it installs Telescope into a Docker container, and I don't really know how I can install react within that container.

Does anybody have any idea what I can do to fix this?

Comment: What is Your server node version?

Comment: New version of Telescope is pretty new, so it may not be totally stable. You can get support on their [Slack channel](https://telescopeapp.slack.com). I believe it currently wants Node 4.x with NPM 3.x to install Telescope deps properly (even though Meteor will use its own version @0.10).

Comment: @Gemmi - My server node version is v4.2.6 and NPM version 3.5.2. But I'm unsure which versions are installed in the docker container on the server.

Comment: @ldg - Unfortunately I can't enter their slack channel. I guess I need to be invited to it.

Comment: See their github page, it has instructions how to join it and other support options.